# Heroku deployment failed - Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, package.json

I have created a simple React application that works locally, but for some reason, Heroku keeps giving me this error message when I try to deploy it. I have been googling for solutions and trying everything I can find, but this error still persists. I am still a beginner in this, and would gladly appreciate any help or advice. If anyone would like to try it, my repository which I am trying to deploy from is https://github.com/shittake/findabudbud. Thank you in advance.

-----> Build
Running build

```
   > findabudbud@1.0.0 build
   > react-scripts build
```

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:361
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/build_2e0389cc/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (/tmp/build_2e0389cc/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:36:12)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
path: '/tmp/build_2e0389cc/node_modules/fs-extra/package.json',
requestPath: 'fs-extra'
}
-----> Build failed

```
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   Some possible problems:
   
   - node_modules checked into source control
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
   
   - Node version not specified in package.json
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
   
   Love,
   Heroku
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
!     Push failed

Comment: I suggest using https://www.netlify.com/ to host your static site instead. Heroku is more used for non static sites... Netlify can configure to your repo. the build command is `npm run build` and thats it.

Comment: so, have you made sure that *node_modules* IS NOT *checked into source control*? have you made sure that *Node version* IS *specified in package.json* - looking at your git repo, it seems, *node_modules* **IS** *checked into source control* and *Node version **IS not** specified in package.json* - the two "possible problems" in the message are two actual problems in your repository